# Django FirstApp

Tags: python, django

I am following the django tutorial (found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/)):

views.py code:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

urls.py code (this is inside polls app urls.py file):

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings


from . import views
urlpatterns = [path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), ]
```

urls.py code ( this is root urls.py file code):

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),path('admin/',admin.site.urls), ]
```

Here is my run command :  `python manage.py runserver 8080`

I tried to run it today, but I am getting the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://35527a91f40c4e228d6c464d8a8c8487.vfs.cloud9.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
Using the URLconf defined in PollApp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

poll/
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Djano errors are self-explanatory, follow its instructions, and are good to go.Also is  there the Indentation in your first return ?

```
from . import views
    
     urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.index, name='index'),
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using regex-syntax with `path`, you should use the empty string instead:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Furthermore, you use a `poll/` prefix here, so that means you either need to visit `localhost:8000/poll/`, or change this to an empty prefix:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```